# Get '0' counts in a convoluted query SQL Server/Argos

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, count

This seems like it should be easy, but I'm having a tough time, because I need 0 counts for grade level, course name and course period. This query technically returns the correct information, but of course doesn't include courses/periods/grade levels where the count of students is 0.

```
SELECT
     SUBSTRING(i5_schedule.course_name,1,10) "Course",
     i5_schedule.Silk_period "Period",
     s.grade_level,
     count(distinct s.stuid) "count"
FROM   
     ( ( ( i5_schedule i5_schedule
     inner join ( ( i5_student s
     inner join evi_User_Table evi_User_Table on (s.stuid =   evi_User_Table.stuid) and (evi_User_Table.syr = s.syr))
     inner join i5_roster i5_roster on (s.attend_dst = i5_roster.dst) and (s.attend_sch = i5_roster.sch) and (s.syr = i5_roster.syr) and (s.stuid = i5_roster.stuid) ) on i5_schedule.schedule_ID = i5_roster.schedule_ID ))
     left join i5_teacher i5_teacher on (i5_schedule.teacher_ID = i5_teacher.teacher_ID) and (i5_schedule.syr = i5_teacher.syr) and (i5_schedule.dst = i5_teacher.dst) and (i5_schedule.sch = i5_teacher.sch))

WHERE 
     evi_User_Table.User_ID = 'A0010833' and
     i5_schedule.syr = 1718 and
     i5_schedule.dst = '004' and
     i5_schedule.sch = '007' and
     i5_schedule.teacher_ID = 5649 and
     i5_schedule.silk_period = 'Per 4'
GROUP BY i5_schedule.course_name,
     i5_schedule.Silk_period, 
     s.grade_level
ORDER BY 
     i5_schedule.silk_period, s.grade_level
```

This query returns one row:

```
  4/5 SHOP    Per 4     06    1
```

I need it to return:

```
  4/5 SHOP    Per 4     06    1
  4/5 SHOP    Per 4     07    0
  4/5 SHOP    Per 4     08    0
  4/5 SHOP    Per 4     09    0
```

etc.
I do have access to another table called i5_grades_taught that can be joined to the other tables on syr, dst, sch, grades. I've tried using that table first then doing outer joins to the other tables, and I just can't get it to work!

I've made this query a little simpler by adding the silk_period filter. When I get this working correctly, I will need to it to return rows for all classes/periods:

```
  Advisory    ADV      06    0
  Advisory    ADV      07    0
  Advisory    ADV      08    0
  Advisory    ADV      09    20
  4/5 SHOP    Per 4    06    1
  4/5 SHOP    Per 4    07    0
  4/5 SHOP    Per 4    08    0
  4/5 SHOP    Per 4    09    0
  MS SHOP     Per 5    06    0
  MS SHOP     Per 5    07    10
  MS SHOP     Per 5    08    1
  MS SHOP     Per 5    09    0
```

Update on what I've tried:

```
SELECT    
    SUBSTRING i5_schedule.course_name,1,10) "Course",                 
    i5_schedule.Silk_period "Period", 
    gt.grade,
    count(distinct s.stuid) "count"
FROM
   i5_grades_taught gt
   LEFT JOIN i5_schedule on gt.syr = i5_schedule.syr and gt.dst =    i5_schedule.dst and gt.sch = i5_schedule.sch
    LEFT JOIN i5_roster on i5_roster.schedule_ID = i5_schedule.schedule_ID
    LEFT JOIN i5_student s on (s.attend_dst = i5_roster.dst) and (s.attend_sch = i5_roster.sch) and (s.syr = i5_roster.syr) and (s.stuid = i5_roster.stuid) and s.grade_level = gt.grade
    LEFT JOIN evi_User_Table evi_User_Table on (s.stuid = evi_User_Table.stuid) and (evi_User_Table.syr = s.syr)
WHERE
    evi_User_Table.User_ID = 'A0010833' and
    i5_schedule.syr = 1718 and
    i5_schedule.dst = '004' and
    i5_schedule.sch = '007' and
    i5_schedule.teacher_ID = 5649 and
    i5_schedule.silk_period = 'Per 4'
GROUP BY
    SUBSTRING(i5_schedule.course_name,1,10),
    i5_schedule.Silk_period,
    gt.grade

ORDER BY
    i5_schedule.silk_period, 
    gt.grade
```

Still not the results I'm looking for. :(

Comment: I think this query can be made a lot simpler. What columns are in your i5_schedule table and i5_student table? Do you have a way to link the 2?

Comment: change the inner joins to left joins. You can't get a count for a schedule that has no students because you are filtering those out by inner joining to students... thus... removing all schedules where there are no student matches. This is the same for your other cases as well

Comment: i5_schedule and i5_student share these fields: syr, dst, sch. I did change all the joins to Left Joins, still didn't return the right results. Returned the same results as the original query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    SUBSTRING(i5_schedule.course_name,1,10) "Course",
    i5_schedule.Silk_period "Period",
    s.grade_level,
    count(distinct s.stuid) "count"
from
    i5_schedule
        join i5_roster on i5_roster.schedule_ID = i5_schedule.schedule_ID
        left join i5_student s on (s.attend_dst = i5_roster.dst) and (s.attend_sch = i5_roster.sch) and (s.syr = i5_roster.syr) and (s.stuid = i5_roster.stuid)
        left join evi_User_Table evi_User_Table on (s.stuid = evi_User_Table.stuid) and (evi_User_Table.syr = s.syr)
where
    evi_User_Table.User_ID = 'A0010833' and
    i5_schedule.syr = 1718 and
    i5_schedule.dst = '004' and
    i5_schedule.sch = '007' and
    i5_schedule.teacher_ID = 5649 and
    i5_schedule.silk_period = 'Per 4'
group by
    SUBSTRING(i5_schedule.course_name,1,10) "Course",
    i5_schedule.Silk_period "Period",
    s.grade_level,
    count(distinct s.stuid) "count"
order by
    i5_schedule.silk_period, 
    s.grade_level
```

Comment: The above code still doesn't work: first error - using aliases in the group by. Removed aliases and count(distinct s.stuid) line from group by, still only returns records with a value > 0. It is much cleaner though! I'm working with legacy code whose original programmer is no longer here to describe why he did what he did, so I just have been rolling with it for the most part. I tried this:

Comment: So using the new query what results do you get?

Comment: Same exact results - only returns records with > 0 results.

Answer (score 0):

Simple code seemed to work for me:

```
  SELECT
   SUBSTRING(i5_schedule.course_name,1,10) "Course",
       i5_schedule.Silk_period "Period",
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.grade_level = '06' then 1 else 0 end) as "G06",
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.grade_level = '07' then 1 else 0 end) as "G07",
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.grade_level = '08' then 1 else 0 end) as "G08",
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.grade_level = '09' then 1 else 0 end) as "G09",
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.grade_level = '10' then 1 else 0 end) as "G10",
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.grade_level = '11' then 1 else 0 end) as "G11",
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.grade_level = '12' then 1 else 0 end) as "G12"

FROM     ( ( ( i5_schedule i5_schedule
  inner join ( ( i5_student s
  inner join evi_User_Table evi_User_Table on (s.stuid = evi_User_Table.stuid) and (evi_User_Table.syr = s.syr) )
  inner join i5_roster i5_roster on (s.attend_dst = i5_roster.dst) and (s.attend_sch = i5_roster.sch) and (s.syr = i5_roster.syr) and (s.stuid = i5_roster.stuid) ) on i5_schedule.schedule_ID = i5_roster.schedule_ID ))
  left join i5_teacher i5_teacher on (i5_schedule.teacher_ID = i5_teacher.teacher_ID) and (i5_schedule.syr = i5_teacher.syr) and (i5_schedule.dst = i5_teacher.dst) and (i5_schedule.sch = i5_teacher.sch))
  LEFT OUTER JOIN evi_DPM_Data dpm on dpm.stuid = s.stuid and dpm.syr = s.syr and dpm.dst = s.attend_dst and dpm.sch = s.attend_sch
  LEFT OUTER JOIN i5_grad_status i5_grad_status on s.syr = i5_grad_status.syr and s.attend_dst =  i5_grad_status.dst and s.attend_sch =  i5_grad_status.sch and s.stuid = i5_grad_status.stuid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN lbl_mra_Pivot mra on mra.stuid = s.stuid
  INNER JOIN i5_grades_taught gt on gt.syr = i5_schedule.syr and gt.dst = i5_schedule.dst and gt.sch = i5_schedule.sch and gt.grade = s.grade_level

WHERE  evi_User_Table.User_ID = :SQL_User_Id.User_Id
   and i5_schedule.syr = :parm_DD_SchoolYear.syr
   and i5_schedule.dst = :parm_DD_District.District
   and i5_schedule.sch = :parm_DD_School.School
   and i5_schedule.teacher_ID = :parm_DD_Teacher.teacher_ID
```